# Force / edit axis values in latticeExtra

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm using one dataset where the variable present in X has only two possible values - 2009 or 2010.

```
2009,01,52.4
2009,01,49.5
2009,01,53.2
2009,01,48.2
2009,01,53.9
2009,01,42.8
2009,01,56.4
2009,01,57
2009,01,50.3
2009,01,57.4
2009,01,45.2
2009,01,55
2009,01,47.1
2009,01,42.2
2009,01,57.1
2009,01,51.7
2009,01,56.8
2009,01,56.9
2009,01,55
2009,01,52.9
2009,01,52.9
2009,01,57
2009,01,45
2009,01,52.8
2009,01,52
2009,01,55.1
2009,01,53.3
2009,01,55.2
2009,01,53.2
2009,01,56.9
2009,01,55.9
2009,02,54.7
2009,02,53.1
2009,02,54.2
2009,02,56.2
2009,02,58.5
2009,02,50.9
2009,02,57.7
2009,02,54.1
2009,02,54.5
2009,02,55.3
2009,02,53.4
2009,02,53.8
2009,02,51.3
2009,02,52.3
2009,02,53
2009,02,53.6
2009,02,55
2009,02,53
2009,02,53.6
2009,02,52.5
2009,02,54.1
2009,02,50.1
2009,02,52.2
2009,02,54.3
2009,02,52.4
2009,02,53.2
2009,02,52.5
2009,02,52.7
2009,03,56.2
2009,03,58.7
2009,03,58.2
2009,03,63
2009,03,55
2009,03,55.4
2009,03,55.8
2009,03,63.8
2009,03,56
2009,03,52.3
2009,03,55.6
2009,03,56.8
2009,03,57.4
2009,03,58.7
2009,03,59.9
2009,03,57.7
2009,03,55.3
2009,03,54.9
2009,03,61.8
2009,03,54.1
2009,03,52.9
2009,03,55.5
2009,03,55.3
2009,03,66.4
2009,03,55.7
2009,03,53.2
2009,04,55.4
2009,04,60
2009,04,54.9
2009,04,55.3
2009,04,57.5
2009,04,55.8
2009,04,57.6
2009,04,55.7
2009,04,56.4
2009,04,54
2009,04,55.8
2009,04,56.8
2009,04,54.8
2009,04,55.8
2009,04,55.8
2009,04,53.5
2009,04,56.8
2009,04,54
2009,04,56.7
2009,04,57.2
2009,04,57.8
2009,04,57.3
2009,04,57.2
2009,04,57.2
2009,04,56.2
2009,04,55.2
2009,04,54.7
2009,04,57
2009,04,55.9
2009,05,59.8
2009,05,58.9
2009,05,59.3
2009,05,58.9
2009,05,60.4
2009,05,59.1
2009,05,58.5
2009,05,73.4
2009,05,62.5
2009,05,61.4
2009,05,61.1
2009,05,61.6
2009,05,67.6
2009,05,66.5
2009,05,58.6
2009,05,61.1
2009,05,62
2009,05,72.1
2009,05,59.3
2009,05,59.6
2009,05,61
2009,05,57.1
2009,05,59.2
2009,05,60.4
2009,05,60.1
2009,05,58.5
2009,05,58.9
2009,05,59.8
2009,05,62.6
2009,05,60.9
2009,05,59.5
2009,06,63.8
2009,06,65.4
2009,06,64.7
2009,06,64
2009,06,65.8
2009,06,68.3
2009,06,63.9
2009,06,64.2
2009,06,61.9
2009,06,62.9
2009,06,63.9
2009,06,69.7
2009,06,63.7
2009,06,63.4
2009,06,63.8
2009,06,64.5
2009,06,64.4
2009,06,63.9
2009,06,66.6
2009,06,70.3
2009,06,67.1
2009,06,65.8
2009,06,65.5
2009,06,62.9
2009,06,64.4
2009,06,65.4
2009,06,64.4
2009,06,63.3
2009,06,66.3
2009,06,66.7
2009,07,64.8
2009,07,66
2009,07,66.8
2009,07,69.9
2009,07,65.9
2009,07,68.6
2009,07,67.6
2009,07,66.7
2009,07,65.5
2009,07,65
2009,07,66.5
2009,07,66.7
2009,07,67.1
2009,07,67.4
2009,07,64.8
2009,07,65.8
2009,07,64.7
2009,07,66
2009,07,68
2009,07,66
2009,07,64.1
2009,07,65.8
2009,07,65
2009,07,63.3
2009,08,65.9
2009,08,65
2009,08,65.9
2009,08,64
2009,08,66.1
2009,08,64.5
2009,08,64
2009,08,66.8
2009,08,65
2009,08,64.7
2009,08,64.8
2009,08,65.8
2009,08,64.9
2009,08,64.9
2009,08,65.1
2009,08,65.2
2009,08,67
2009,08,64.8
2009,08,65.6
2009,08,66.1
2009,08,64.9
2009,08,67.1
2009,08,64.7
2009,08,64.9
2009,08,65.1
2009,08,64.1
2009,08,64.6
2009,08,66.5
2009,08,65.4
2009,08,65
2009,09,64.2
2009,09,63.1
2009,09,65.3
2009,09,64.2
2009,09,64.7
2009,09,63.9
2009,09,70.9
2009,09,70.1
2009,09,65
2009,09,65.5
2009,09,65.4
2009,09,68.1
2009,09,64.4
2009,09,65.1
2009,09,65.7
2009,09,63.2
2009,09,64.5
2009,09,64.8
2009,09,66.4
2009,09,64.9
2009,09,67.5
2009,09,66.4
2009,09,65.7
2009,09,65
2009,09,64.4
2009,09,62.5
2009,09,62.9
2009,09,63.7
2009,09,63.3
2009,10,66.6
2009,10,62.9
2009,10,63.1
2009,10,65.4
2009,10,69.4
2009,10,71.1
2009,10,64.1
2009,10,66.9
2009,10,69.4
2009,10,66.6
2009,10,63
2009,10,67.2
2009,10,68.6
2009,10,65.2
2009,10,64
2009,10,62.4
2009,10,65
2009,10,64.3
2009,10,68.6
2009,10,68
2009,10,63
2009,10,61.2
2009,10,65.3
2009,10,64.7
2009,10,67.1
2009,10,67.2
2009,10,68.5
2009,10,65.4
2009,10,64
2009,11,58.4
2009,11,66.4
2009,11,58.2
2009,11,55.7
2009,11,59.4
2009,11,62.7
2009,11,61.5
2009,11,62.2
2009,11,63.8
2009,11,62.2
2009,11,59.9
2009,11,62.5
2009,11,61.8
2009,11,63.3
2009,11,60.5
2009,11,60
2009,11,62
2009,11,60.5
2009,11,59.4
2009,11,63
2009,11,61.8
2009,11,60.6
2009,11,62.2
2009,11,62.9
2009,11,59.3
2009,11,55.6
2009,11,61.2
2009,11,57.6
2009,11,63.3
2009,11,58.1
2009,12,45.6
2009,12,59.7
2009,12,59.4
2009,12,59.5
2009,12,58
2009,12,56.5
2009,12,60.3
2009,12,55.9
2009,12,50.6
2009,12,51.3
2009,12,62.3
2009,12,58.2
2009,12,40.6
2009,12,59.4
2009,12,55.6
2009,12,61.6
2009,12,48.1
2009,12,52.3
2009,12,57.7
2009,12,60.1
2009,12,61.3
2009,12,59.7
2009,12,52.6
2009,12,51.9
2009,12,53.2
2009,12,58.7
2009,12,55.9
2010,01,57.8
2010,01,45.4
2010,01,50.5
2010,01,56.3
2010,01,58.1
2010,01,41.8
2010,01,53
2010,01,58.9
2010,01,52.5
2010,01,50.5
2010,01,56.4
2010,01,55.9
2010,01,55.4
2010,01,39
2010,01,56.4
2010,01,57.7
2010,01,59.8
2010,01,54.9
2010,01,56.1
2010,01,55.6
2010,01,57.5
2010,01,47.4
2010,01,59.5
2010,01,48.7
2010,01,59.4
2010,01,55.5
2010,01,56.3
2010,01,45.1
2010,01,49
2010,02,43.1
2010,02,53.9
2010,02,44.2
2010,02,53.2
2010,02,48.8
2010,02,44.3
2010,02,57.3
2010,02,50.4
2010,02,59.8
2010,02,58.5
2010,02,56.3
2010,02,56.7
2010,02,58.9
2010,02,51.3
2010,02,43
2010,02,58.4
2010,02,56.9
2010,02,57.2
2010,02,51.2
2010,02,50.9
2010,02,48.7
2010,02,54.4
2010,02,55.9
2010,02,53.9
2010,02,59.3
2010,03,56
2010,03,54.9
2010,03,55.9
2010,03,58.2
2010,03,60.9
2010,03,56
2010,03,57.5
2010,03,59.1
2010,03,57.4
2010,03,51.9
2010,03,58
2010,03,55.9
2010,03,57.1
2010,03,55
2010,03,60.7
2010,03,55.7
2010,03,50.3
2010,03,57.6
2010,03,60.5
2010,03,53.7
2010,03,56.5
2010,03,57.3
2010,03,52.8
2010,03,46.7
2010,03,52.3
2010,03,55.6
2010,03,52.7
2010,03,56.1
2010,03,57.1
2010,03,55.2
2010,03,57.6
2010,04,62.4
2010,04,62.6
2010,04,55.7
2010,04,62.5
2010,04,57.5
2010,04,69.5
2010,04,63.5
2010,04,62.2
2010,04,60.7
2010,04,62.5
2010,04,62
2010,04,57.6
2010,04,61.3
2010,04,54.8
2010,04,64.3
2010,04,61.4
2010,04,67.2
2010,04,63
2010,04,64.5
2010,04,57.3
2010,04,57.4
2010,04,55.8
2010,04,58.6
2010,04,60.6
2010,04,61
2010,04,56.9
2010,04,60.2
2010,04,65.3
2010,04,60.2
2010,04,59.6
2010,05,73.9
2010,05,63.3
2010,05,56.5
2010,05,63.7
2010,05,63.2
2010,05,58.9
2010,05,58.1
2010,05,71.3
2010,05,63
2010,05,64.8
2010,05,64.1
2010,05,58.6
2010,05,55.9
2010,05,57.7
2010,05,69.1
2010,05,61.4
2010,05,59.2
2010,05,58.5
2010,05,57.3
2010,05,60.2
2010,05,59.1
2010,05,67.8
2010,05,67.1
2010,05,64.7
2010,05,61.3
2010,05,58.5
2010,05,58.7
2010,05,61.7
2010,05,59.9
2010,05,65.2
2010,06,64.4
2010,06,62
2010,06,62.2
2010,06,62.7
2010,06,65.8
2010,06,65.1
2010,06,63.4
2010,06,63.3
2010,06,62.2
2010,06,61.8
2010,06,61.5
2010,06,61.7
2010,06,64.7
2010,06,62.8
2010,06,64.2
2010,06,61.4
2010,06,63.3
2010,06,62.8
2010,06,64.1
2010,06,60.5
2010,06,62.6
2010,06,62.2
2010,06,63.1
2010,06,62.9
2010,06,63
2010,06,62.5
2010,06,62.2
2010,06,63.9
2010,06,61.9
2010,06,64.3
2010,07,65
2010,07,65.3
2010,07,65.1
2010,07,65.6
2010,07,65.6
2010,07,69.8
2010,07,74.5
2010,07,64.7
2010,07,65.6
2010,07,64.6
2010,07,72.1
2010,07,66.4
2010,07,66.8
2010,07,63.7
2010,07,65.2
2010,07,63.8
2010,07,65
2010,07,66.5
2010,07,65.4
2010,07,67.1
2010,07,65.5
2010,07,66.3
2010,07,65.9
2010,07,65.5
2010,07,64.5
2010,07,65
2010,07,65.9
2010,07,64.8
2010,07,65.3
2010,07,64.8
2010,07,65.3
2010,08,65.6
2010,08,65.5
2010,08,67
2010,08,69.4
2010,08,65
2010,08,64.3
2010,08,66.9
2010,08,65.4
2010,08,64.4
2010,08,65.1
2010,08,66.4
2010,08,63.6
2010,08,65.2
2010,08,63.3
2010,08,70.1
2010,08,65.9
2010,08,68.3
2010,08,67.8
2010,08,64.4
2010,08,65.1
2010,08,64.7
2010,08,63.7
2010,08,63.5
2010,08,67.9
2010,08,70.3
2010,08,65.8
2010,08,63.9
2010,08,66.6
2010,08,67.4
2010,08,65.4
2010,08,64.1
2010,09,66.6
2010,09,70.7
2010,09,66.3
2010,09,64.5
2010,09,66.7
2010,09,68.1
2010,09,71.2
2010,09,64.4
2010,09,65
2010,09,67.8
2010,09,64.5
2010,09,66.7
2010,09,67.8
2010,09,67.6
2010,09,68.3
2010,09,67.8
2010,09,67.6
2010,09,66.4
2010,09,68.4
2010,09,67.6
2010,09,63.7
2010,09,72.2
2010,09,67.3
2010,09,67.6
2010,09,67.6
2010,09,68.4
2010,09,64.7
2010,09,68.6
2010,09,66.4
2010,10,62
2010,10,63.3
2010,10,63.6
2010,10,63.7
2010,10,61.8
2010,10,64.2
2010,10,62.9
2010,10,65.6
2010,10,64.1
2010,10,65.2
2010,10,64.8
2010,10,61.6
2010,10,64.7
2010,10,65.7
2010,10,60.9
2010,10,61.7
2010,10,65.1
2010,10,65.5
2010,10,61
2010,10,62.1
2010,10,63
2010,10,65.8
2010,10,64.3
2010,10,65.3
2010,10,64.8
2010,10,62.5
2010,10,60.7
2010,11,61.2
2010,11,60.4
```

and this code

```
library(latticeExtra)

heisenberg <- read.csv(file="ABSOLUTE_FILE_LOCATION")

x <- heisenberg[[1]]
y <- heisenberg[[2]]
z <- heisenberg[[3]]

cloud(z~x+y, heisenberg, panel.3d.cloud=panel.3dbars, col.facet='green',
      xbase=0.4, ybase=0.4,scales=list(arrows=FALSE, col=1), 
      par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")))
```

to create this 3D bar chart

[image: 3D Bar Chart]

Thing is, i want the X axis to have only 2009 and 2010 instead of 2009.0, 2009.2, 2009.4 ...

I added new entries to the code and when the entry was three years before the smallest year value or three years after the highest year value,

> 2006,01,20

[image: Lattice Extra with new data entry]

or

> 2013,01,20

[image: Lattice Extra with new data entry]

didn't break the axis values.

This isn't the best solution because it introduces data that's not part of the original into the dataset but it's better than nothing.

Serves this question to know how to force the X axis to have **only** the 2 possible values, in the axis variable, without breaking them into many?

Comment: you can set the axis ticks `scales=list(arrows=FALSE, col=1, x=list(at=2009:2010))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only a matter of adding [`as.factor`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/factor) to express that 2009 and 2010 are ordinal and not continuous I think. That is,

```
x <- heisenberg[[1]]
x <- factor(x, levels = c(2009, 2010), ordered = TRUE) ## The only difference
y <- heisenberg[[2]]
z <- heisenberg[[3]]

cloud(
  z ~ x + y, heisenberg,
  panel.3d.cloud = panel.3dbars, col.facet = "green",
  xbase = 0.4, ybase = 0.4, scales = list(arrows = FALSE, col = 1),
  par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent"))
)
```

Then you would have the following plot:

[image]

Let me know if this wasn't what you were going for.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you @Kim. The bounty can only be awarded in 11 hours, but you don't need to worry, I'm giving it to you.