# r - Force / edit axis values in plot3D

Tags: r, plot3d

In my [most recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58783617/9415908) I faced a problem having to do with the axis when using a different library.

In this particular case, I'm using the same dataset where the variable present in X has only two possible values - 2009 or 2010.

```
2009,01,52.4
2009,01,49.5
2009,01,53.2
2009,01,48.2
2009,01,53.9
2009,01,42.8
2009,01,56.4
2009,01,57
2009,01,50.3
2009,01,57.4
2009,01,45.2
2009,01,55
2009,01,47.1
2009,01,42.2
2009,01,57.1
2009,01,51.7
2009,01,56.8
2009,01,56.9
2009,01,55
2009,01,52.9
2009,01,52.9
2009,01,57
2009,01,45
2009,01,52.8
2009,01,52
2009,01,55.1
2009,01,53.3
2009,01,55.2
2009,01,53.2
2009,01,56.9
2009,01,55.9
2009,02,54.7
2009,02,53.1
2009,02,54.2
2009,02,56.2
2009,02,58.5
2009,02,50.9
2009,02,57.7
2009,02,54.1
2009,02,54.5
2009,02,55.3
2009,02,53.4
2009,02,53.8
2009,02,51.3
2009,02,52.3
2009,02,53
2009,02,53.6
2009,02,55
2009,02,53
2009,02,53.6
2009,02,52.5
2009,02,54.1
2009,02,50.1
2009,02,52.2
2009,02,54.3
2009,02,52.4
2009,02,53.2
2009,02,52.5
2009,02,52.7
2009,03,56.2
2009,03,58.7
2009,03,58.2
2009,03,63
2009,03,55
2009,03,55.4
2009,03,55.8
2009,03,63.8
2009,03,56
2009,03,52.3
2009,03,55.6
2009,03,56.8
2009,03,57.4
2009,03,58.7
2009,03,59.9
2009,03,57.7
2009,03,55.3
2009,03,54.9
2009,03,61.8
2009,03,54.1
2009,03,52.9
2009,03,55.5
2009,03,55.3
2009,03,66.4
2009,03,55.7
2009,03,53.2
2009,04,55.4
2009,04,60
2009,04,54.9
2009,04,55.3
2009,04,57.5
2009,04,55.8
2009,04,57.6
2009,04,55.7
2009,04,56.4
2009,04,54
2009,04,55.8
2009,04,56.8
2009,04,54.8
2009,04,55.8
2009,04,55.8
2009,04,53.5
2009,04,56.8
2009,04,54
2009,04,56.7
2009,04,57.2
2009,04,57.8
2009,04,57.3
2009,04,57.2
2009,04,57.2
2009,04,56.2
2009,04,55.2
2009,04,54.7
2009,04,57
2009,04,55.9
2009,05,59.8
2009,05,58.9
2009,05,59.3
2009,05,58.9
2009,05,60.4
2009,05,59.1
2009,05,58.5
2009,05,73.4
2009,05,62.5
2009,05,61.4
2009,05,61.1
2009,05,61.6
2009,05,67.6
2009,05,66.5
2009,05,58.6
2009,05,61.1
2009,05,62
2009,05,72.1
2009,05,59.3
2009,05,59.6
2009,05,61
2009,05,57.1
2009,05,59.2
2009,05,60.4
2009,05,60.1
2009,05,58.5
2009,05,58.9
2009,05,59.8
2009,05,62.6
2009,05,60.9
2009,05,59.5
2009,06,63.8
2009,06,65.4
2009,06,64.7
2009,06,64
2009,06,65.8
2009,06,68.3
2009,06,63.9
2009,06,64.2
2009,06,61.9
2009,06,62.9
2009,06,63.9
2009,06,69.7
2009,06,63.7
2009,06,63.4
2009,06,63.8
2009,06,64.5
2009,06,64.4
2009,06,63.9
2009,06,66.6
2009,06,70.3
2009,06,67.1
2009,06,65.8
2009,06,65.5
2009,06,62.9
2009,06,64.4
2009,06,65.4
2009,06,64.4
2009,06,63.3
2009,06,66.3
2009,06,66.7
2009,07,64.8
2009,07,66
2009,07,66.8
2009,07,69.9
2009,07,65.9
2009,07,68.6
2009,07,67.6
2009,07,66.7
2009,07,65.5
2009,07,65
2009,07,66.5
2009,07,66.7
2009,07,67.1
2009,07,67.4
2009,07,64.8
2009,07,65.8
2009,07,64.7
2009,07,66
2009,07,68
2009,07,66
2009,07,64.1
2009,07,65.8
2009,07,65
2009,07,63.3
2009,08,65.9
2009,08,65
2009,08,65.9
2009,08,64
2009,08,66.1
2009,08,64.5
2009,08,64
2009,08,66.8
2009,08,65
2009,08,64.7
2009,08,64.8
2009,08,65.8
2009,08,64.9
2009,08,64.9
2009,08,65.1
2009,08,65.2
2009,08,67
2009,08,64.8
2009,08,65.6
2009,08,66.1
2009,08,64.9
2009,08,67.1
2009,08,64.7
2009,08,64.9
2009,08,65.1
2009,08,64.1
2009,08,64.6
2009,08,66.5
2009,08,65.4
2009,08,65
2009,09,64.2
2009,09,63.1
2009,09,65.3
2009,09,64.2
2009,09,64.7
2009,09,63.9
2009,09,70.9
2009,09,70.1
2009,09,65
2009,09,65.5
2009,09,65.4
2009,09,68.1
2009,09,64.4
2009,09,65.1
2009,09,65.7
2009,09,63.2
2009,09,64.5
2009,09,64.8
2009,09,66.4
2009,09,64.9
2009,09,67.5
2009,09,66.4
2009,09,65.7
2009,09,65
2009,09,64.4
2009,09,62.5
2009,09,62.9
2009,09,63.7
2009,09,63.3
2009,10,66.6
2009,10,62.9
2009,10,63.1
2009,10,65.4
2009,10,69.4
2009,10,71.1
2009,10,64.1
2009,10,66.9
2009,10,69.4
2009,10,66.6
2009,10,63
2009,10,67.2
2009,10,68.6
2009,10,65.2
2009,10,64
2009,10,62.4
2009,10,65
2009,10,64.3
2009,10,68.6
2009,10,68
2009,10,63
2009,10,61.2
2009,10,65.3
2009,10,64.7
2009,10,67.1
2009,10,67.2
2009,10,68.5
2009,10,65.4
2009,10,64
2009,11,58.4
2009,11,66.4
2009,11,58.2
2009,11,55.7
2009,11,59.4
2009,11,62.7
2009,11,61.5
2009,11,62.2
2009,11,63.8
2009,11,62.2
2009,11,59.9
2009,11,62.5
2009,11,61.8
2009,11,63.3
2009,11,60.5
2009,11,60
2009,11,62
2009,11,60.5
2009,11,59.4
2009,11,63
2009,11,61.8
2009,11,60.6
2009,11,62.2
2009,11,62.9
2009,11,59.3
2009,11,55.6
2009,11,61.2
2009,11,57.6
2009,11,63.3
2009,11,58.1
2009,12,45.6
2009,12,59.7
2009,12,59.4
2009,12,59.5
2009,12,58
2009,12,56.5
2009,12,60.3
2009,12,55.9
2009,12,50.6
2009,12,51.3
2009,12,62.3
2009,12,58.2
2009,12,40.6
2009,12,59.4
2009,12,55.6
2009,12,61.6
2009,12,48.1
2009,12,52.3
2009,12,57.7
2009,12,60.1
2009,12,61.3
2009,12,59.7
2009,12,52.6
2009,12,51.9
2009,12,53.2
2009,12,58.7
2009,12,55.9
2010,01,57.8
2010,01,45.4
2010,01,50.5
2010,01,56.3
2010,01,58.1
2010,01,41.8
2010,01,53
2010,01,58.9
2010,01,52.5
2010,01,50.5
2010,01,56.4
2010,01,55.9
2010,01,55.4
2010,01,39
2010,01,56.4
2010,01,57.7
2010,01,59.8
2010,01,54.9
2010,01,56.1
2010,01,55.6
2010,01,57.5
2010,01,47.4
2010,01,59.5
2010,01,48.7
2010,01,59.4
2010,01,55.5
2010,01,56.3
2010,01,45.1
2010,01,49
2010,02,43.1
2010,02,53.9
2010,02,44.2
2010,02,53.2
2010,02,48.8
2010,02,44.3
2010,02,57.3
2010,02,50.4
2010,02,59.8
2010,02,58.5
2010,02,56.3
2010,02,56.7
2010,02,58.9
2010,02,51.3
2010,02,43
2010,02,58.4
2010,02,56.9
2010,02,57.2
2010,02,51.2
2010,02,50.9
2010,02,48.7
2010,02,54.4
2010,02,55.9
2010,02,53.9
2010,02,59.3
2010,03,56
2010,03,54.9
2010,03,55.9
2010,03,58.2
2010,03,60.9
2010,03,56
2010,03,57.5
2010,03,59.1
2010,03,57.4
2010,03,51.9
2010,03,58
2010,03,55.9
2010,03,57.1
2010,03,55
2010,03,60.7
2010,03,55.7
2010,03,50.3
2010,03,57.6
2010,03,60.5
2010,03,53.7
2010,03,56.5
2010,03,57.3
2010,03,52.8
2010,03,46.7
2010,03,52.3
2010,03,55.6
2010,03,52.7
2010,03,56.1
2010,03,57.1
2010,03,55.2
2010,03,57.6
2010,04,62.4
2010,04,62.6
2010,04,55.7
2010,04,62.5
2010,04,57.5
2010,04,69.5
2010,04,63.5
2010,04,62.2
2010,04,60.7
2010,04,62.5
2010,04,62
2010,04,57.6
2010,04,61.3
2010,04,54.8
2010,04,64.3
2010,04,61.4
2010,04,67.2
2010,04,63
2010,04,64.5
2010,04,57.3
2010,04,57.4
2010,04,55.8
2010,04,58.6
2010,04,60.6
2010,04,61
2010,04,56.9
2010,04,60.2
2010,04,65.3
2010,04,60.2
2010,04,59.6
2010,05,73.9
2010,05,63.3
2010,05,56.5
2010,05,63.7
2010,05,63.2
2010,05,58.9
2010,05,58.1
2010,05,71.3
2010,05,63
2010,05,64.8
2010,05,64.1
2010,05,58.6
2010,05,55.9
2010,05,57.7
2010,05,69.1
2010,05,61.4
2010,05,59.2
2010,05,58.5
2010,05,57.3
2010,05,60.2
2010,05,59.1
2010,05,67.8
2010,05,67.1
2010,05,64.7
2010,05,61.3
2010,05,58.5
2010,05,58.7
2010,05,61.7
2010,05,59.9
2010,05,65.2
2010,06,64.4
2010,06,62
2010,06,62.2
2010,06,62.7
2010,06,65.8
2010,06,65.1
2010,06,63.4
2010,06,63.3
2010,06,62.2
2010,06,61.8
2010,06,61.5
2010,06,61.7
2010,06,64.7
2010,06,62.8
2010,06,64.2
2010,06,61.4
2010,06,63.3
2010,06,62.8
2010,06,64.1
2010,06,60.5
2010,06,62.6
2010,06,62.2
2010,06,63.1
2010,06,62.9
2010,06,63
2010,06,62.5
2010,06,62.2
2010,06,63.9
2010,06,61.9
2010,06,64.3
2010,07,65
2010,07,65.3
2010,07,65.1
2010,07,65.6
2010,07,65.6
2010,07,69.8
2010,07,74.5
2010,07,64.7
2010,07,65.6
2010,07,64.6
2010,07,72.1
2010,07,66.4
2010,07,66.8
2010,07,63.7
2010,07,65.2
2010,07,63.8
2010,07,65
2010,07,66.5
2010,07,65.4
2010,07,67.1
2010,07,65.5
2010,07,66.3
2010,07,65.9
2010,07,65.5
2010,07,64.5
2010,07,65
2010,07,65.9
2010,07,64.8
2010,07,65.3
2010,07,64.8
2010,07,65.3
2010,08,65.6
2010,08,65.5
2010,08,67
2010,08,69.4
2010,08,65
2010,08,64.3
2010,08,66.9
2010,08,65.4
2010,08,64.4
2010,08,65.1
2010,08,66.4
2010,08,63.6
2010,08,65.2
2010,08,63.3
2010,08,70.1
2010,08,65.9
2010,08,68.3
2010,08,67.8
2010,08,64.4
2010,08,65.1
2010,08,64.7
2010,08,63.7
2010,08,63.5
2010,08,67.9
2010,08,70.3
2010,08,65.8
2010,08,63.9
2010,08,66.6
2010,08,67.4
2010,08,65.4
2010,08,64.1
2010,09,66.6
2010,09,70.7
2010,09,66.3
2010,09,64.5
2010,09,66.7
2010,09,68.1
2010,09,71.2
2010,09,64.4
2010,09,65
2010,09,67.8
2010,09,64.5
2010,09,66.7
2010,09,67.8
2010,09,67.6
2010,09,68.3
2010,09,67.8
2010,09,67.6
2010,09,66.4
2010,09,68.4
2010,09,67.6
2010,09,63.7
2010,09,72.2
2010,09,67.3
2010,09,67.6
2010,09,67.6
2010,09,68.4
2010,09,64.7
2010,09,68.6
2010,09,66.4
2010,10,62
2010,10,63.3
2010,10,63.6
2010,10,63.7
2010,10,61.8
2010,10,64.2
2010,10,62.9
2010,10,65.6
2010,10,64.1
2010,10,65.2
2010,10,64.8
2010,10,61.6
2010,10,64.7
2010,10,65.7
2010,10,60.9
2010,10,61.7
2010,10,65.1
2010,10,65.5
2010,10,61
2010,10,62.1
2010,10,63
2010,10,65.8
2010,10,64.3
2010,10,65.3
2010,10,64.8
2010,10,62.5
2010,10,60.7
2010,11,61.2
2010,11,60.4
```

and if I run the following code

```
library(plot3D)

heisenberg <- read.csv(file="ABSOLUTE_FILE_LOCATION")

x <- heisenberg[[1]]
y <- heisenberg[[2]]
z <- heisenberg[[3]]


points3D(x, y, z, ticktype = "detailed")
```

I get

[image: points3D with wrong axis]

Thing is, i want the X axis to have only 2009 and 2010 instead of 2009.0, 2009.2, 2009.4 ...

In `latticeExtra` [adding a factor solved the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58809279/9415908).

Just like in the other question, if I add two entries to the data, I'm able to get the following result, which is closer than what I want but introduces wrong data.

[image: points3D R]

So, I decided to add the factor in a similar way like how the other was solved, I get the following error

> Error in Math.factor(diff(xlim)) : ‘abs’ not meaningful for factors

This error means I'm applying `abs()` to an object type factor and it's not liking.

Considering the function `factor()` allowed me to assign an order to the nominal variables, thus making them ordinal variables, if I [convert the factor to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4798794/9415908) is expected to not fix this and I would get the same result

```
library(plot3D)

heisenberg <- read.csv(file="ABSOLUTE_FILE_LOCATION")

x <- heisenberg[[1]]
x <- factor(x, levels = c(2009, 2010), ordered = TRUE)
x <- as.numeric(levels(x))[x]
y <- heisenberg[[2]]
z <- heisenberg[[3]]


points3D(x, y, z, ticktype = "detailed")
```

which was as expected.

So, considering such scenario, what then can I do to fix this?

Comment: I would say that trying to plot this data on a 3D graph is just never going to give a satisfying result since one of your variables is really categorical data (despite being a number). If you're trying to present this in a meaningful way you'd do better to just use two 2d plots side by side, or overlay the plot for 2010 on top of the plot for 2009 and use a different color for the two plots.

Comment: Hi @MaDMaDMad that isn't an option to consider here though

Comment: I think the real answer is use something other than plot3D.

`points3D(x, y, z, ticktype = "detailed",
         nticks = 2)` Might work

Comment: Ups, I just see now your comment, @dyrland (not refreshed the page while I was playing at Rstudio). Molecoder, feel free to give the answer (and the bounty) to they if an answer is provided ;)

Comment: I'm in it for the knowledge not the bounty!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
heisenberg <- structure(list(x = c(2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
                                   2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                   2010L, 2010L, 2010L), y = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                               2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                               2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                               3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                               4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                               4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                               5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                               5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
                                                               6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
                                                               6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
                                                               7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
                                                               8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
                                                               8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
                                                               9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
                                                               9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
                                                               10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
                                                               10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
                                                               11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
                                                               11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
                                                               11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
                                                               12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
                                                               12L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                               1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                               2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                               3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                               3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                               4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                               4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                               5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                               5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
                                                               6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
                                                               6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
                                                               7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
                                                               7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
                                                               8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
                                                               8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
                                                               9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
                                                               10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
                                                               10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
                                                               11L, 11L), z = c(52.4, 49.5, 53.2, 48.2, 53.9, 42.8, 56.4, 57, 
                                                                                50.3, 57.4, 45.2, 55, 47.1, 42.2, 57.1, 51.7, 56.8, 56.9, 55, 
                                                                                52.9, 52.9, 57, 45, 52.8, 52, 55.1, 53.3, 55.2, 53.2, 56.9, 55.9, 
                                                                                54.7, 53.1, 54.2, 56.2, 58.5, 50.9, 57.7, 54.1, 54.5, 55.3, 53.4, 
                                                                                53.8, 51.3, 52.3, 53, 53.6, 55, 53, 53.6, 52.5, 54.1, 50.1, 52.2, 
                                                                                54.3, 52.4, 53.2, 52.5, 52.7, 56.2, 58.7, 58.2, 63, 55, 55.4, 
                                                                                55.8, 63.8, 56, 52.3, 55.6, 56.8, 57.4, 58.7, 59.9, 57.7, 55.3, 
                                                                                54.9, 61.8, 54.1, 52.9, 55.5, 55.3, 66.4, 55.7, 53.2, 55.4, 60, 
                                                                                54.9, 55.3, 57.5, 55.8, 57.6, 55.7, 56.4, 54, 55.8, 56.8, 54.8, 
                                                                                55.8, 55.8, 53.5, 56.8, 54, 56.7, 57.2, 57.8, 57.3, 57.2, 57.2, 
                                                                                56.2, 55.2, 54.7, 57, 55.9, 59.8, 58.9, 59.3, 58.9, 60.4, 59.1, 
                                                                                58.5, 73.4, 62.5, 61.4, 61.1, 61.6, 67.6, 66.5, 58.6, 61.1, 62, 
                                                                                72.1, 59.3, 59.6, 61, 57.1, 59.2, 60.4, 60.1, 58.5, 58.9, 59.8, 
                                                                                62.6, 60.9, 59.5, 63.8, 65.4, 64.7, 64, 65.8, 68.3, 63.9, 64.2, 
                                                                                61.9, 62.9, 63.9, 69.7, 63.7, 63.4, 63.8, 64.5, 64.4, 63.9, 66.6, 
                                                                                70.3, 67.1, 65.8, 65.5, 62.9, 64.4, 65.4, 64.4, 63.3, 66.3, 66.7, 
                                                                                64.8, 66, 66.8, 69.9, 65.9, 68.6, 67.6, 66.7, 65.5, 65, 66.5, 
                                                                                66.7, 67.1, 67.4, 64.8, 65.8, 64.7, 66, 68, 66, 64.1, 65.8, 65, 
                                                                                63.3, 65.9, 65, 65.9, 64, 66.1, 64.5, 64, 66.8, 65, 64.7, 64.8, 
                                                                                65.8, 64.9, 64.9, 65.1, 65.2, 67, 64.8, 65.6, 66.1, 64.9, 67.1, 
                                                                                64.7, 64.9, 65.1, 64.1, 64.6, 66.5, 65.4, 65, 64.2, 63.1, 65.3, 
                                                                                64.2, 64.7, 63.9, 70.9, 70.1, 65, 65.5, 65.4, 68.1, 64.4, 65.1, 
                                                                                65.7, 63.2, 64.5, 64.8, 66.4, 64.9, 67.5, 66.4, 65.7, 65, 64.4, 
                                                                                62.5, 62.9, 63.7, 63.3, 66.6, 62.9, 63.1, 65.4, 69.4, 71.1, 64.1, 
                                                                                66.9, 69.4, 66.6, 63, 67.2, 68.6, 65.2, 64, 62.4, 65, 64.3, 68.6, 
                                                                                68, 63, 61.2, 65.3, 64.7, 67.1, 67.2, 68.5, 65.4, 64, 58.4, 66.4, 
                                                                                58.2, 55.7, 59.4, 62.7, 61.5, 62.2, 63.8, 62.2, 59.9, 62.5, 61.8, 
                                                                                63.3, 60.5, 60, 62, 60.5, 59.4, 63, 61.8, 60.6, 62.2, 62.9, 59.3, 
                                                                                55.6, 61.2, 57.6, 63.3, 58.1, 45.6, 59.7, 59.4, 59.5, 58, 56.5, 
                                                                                60.3, 55.9, 50.6, 51.3, 62.3, 58.2, 40.6, 59.4, 55.6, 61.6, 48.1, 
                                                                                52.3, 57.7, 60.1, 61.3, 59.7, 52.6, 51.9, 53.2, 58.7, 55.9, 57.8, 
                                                                                45.4, 50.5, 56.3, 58.1, 41.8, 53, 58.9, 52.5, 50.5, 56.4, 55.9, 
                                                                                55.4, 39, 56.4, 57.7, 59.8, 54.9, 56.1, 55.6, 57.5, 47.4, 59.5, 
                                                                                48.7, 59.4, 55.5, 56.3, 45.1, 49, 43.1, 53.9, 44.2, 53.2, 48.8, 
                                                                                44.3, 57.3, 50.4, 59.8, 58.5, 56.3, 56.7, 58.9, 51.3, 43, 58.4, 
                                                                                56.9, 57.2, 51.2, 50.9, 48.7, 54.4, 55.9, 53.9, 59.3, 56, 54.9, 
                                                                                55.9, 58.2, 60.9, 56, 57.5, 59.1, 57.4, 51.9, 58, 55.9, 57.1, 
                                                                                55, 60.7, 55.7, 50.3, 57.6, 60.5, 53.7, 56.5, 57.3, 52.8, 46.7, 
                                                                                52.3, 55.6, 52.7, 56.1, 57.1, 55.2, 57.6, 62.4, 62.6, 55.7, 62.5, 
                                                                                57.5, 69.5, 63.5, 62.2, 60.7, 62.5, 62, 57.6, 61.3, 54.8, 64.3, 
                                                                                61.4, 67.2, 63, 64.5, 57.3, 57.4, 55.8, 58.6, 60.6, 61, 56.9, 
                                                                                60.2, 65.3, 60.2, 59.6, 73.9, 63.3, 56.5, 63.7, 63.2, 58.9, 58.1, 
                                                                                71.3, 63, 64.8, 64.1, 58.6, 55.9, 57.7, 69.1, 61.4, 59.2, 58.5, 
                                                                                57.3, 60.2, 59.1, 67.8, 67.1, 64.7, 61.3, 58.5, 58.7, 61.7, 59.9, 
                                                                                65.2, 64.4, 62, 62.2, 62.7, 65.8, 65.1, 63.4, 63.3, 62.2, 61.8, 
                                                                                61.5, 61.7, 64.7, 62.8, 64.2, 61.4, 63.3, 62.8, 64.1, 60.5, 62.6, 
                                                                                62.2, 63.1, 62.9, 63, 62.5, 62.2, 63.9, 61.9, 64.3, 65, 65.3, 
                                                                                65.1, 65.6, 65.6, 69.8, 74.5, 64.7, 65.6, 64.6, 72.1, 66.4, 66.8, 
                                                                                63.7, 65.2, 63.8, 65, 66.5, 65.4, 67.1, 65.5, 66.3, 65.9, 65.5, 
                                                                                64.5, 65, 65.9, 64.8, 65.3, 64.8, 65.3, 65.6, 65.5, 67, 69.4, 
                                                                                65, 64.3, 66.9, 65.4, 64.4, 65.1, 66.4, 63.6, 65.2, 63.3, 70.1, 
                                                                                65.9, 68.3, 67.8, 64.4, 65.1, 64.7, 63.7, 63.5, 67.9, 70.3, 65.8, 
                                                                                63.9, 66.6, 67.4, 65.4, 64.1, 66.6, 70.7, 66.3, 64.5, 66.7, 68.1, 
                                                                                71.2, 64.4, 65, 67.8, 64.5, 66.7, 67.8, 67.6, 68.3, 67.8, 67.6, 
                                                                                66.4, 68.4, 67.6, 63.7, 72.2, 67.3, 67.6, 67.6, 68.4, 64.7, 68.6, 
                                                                                66.4, 62, 63.3, 63.6, 63.7, 61.8, 64.2, 62.9, 65.6, 64.1, 65.2, 
                                                                                64.8, 61.6, 64.7, 65.7, 60.9, 61.7, 65.1, 65.5, 61, 62.1, 63, 
                                                                                65.8, 64.3, 65.3, 64.8, 62.5, 60.7, 61.2, 60.4)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                            "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -639L), spec = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                              cols = list(x = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
                                                                                                                                                                                          "collector")), y = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "collector")), z = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))

library(plot3D)

x <- heisenberg[[1]]
y <- heisenberg[[2]]
z <- heisenberg[[3]]

points3D(x, y, z, ticktype = "detailed", xlim = c(2008, 2011), nticks = 4)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

In `points3D(x, y, z, ticktype = "detailed", xlim = c(2008, 2011), nticks = 4)` `nticks` do the trick, as explained [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.1/topics/persp)